# My schema is not showing in the Schema List Window

Tags: schema, database-schema, create-table

Use MySQL Workbench to Create database product;
Output: 1 Create database product   1 row(s) affected.

When I use SHOW databases command, it returns my product schema along with other.
But in the in the Schema list window my schema is not showing.

How can I see it on the Schema list to create tables under Product schema?
I am very new in MySQL environment, please help me with steps to resolve the problem.

Created a schema called product using MySQL Workbench
Its not appearing on the schema list but if I use SHOW database command it returns my schema
How can I make my schema shown on the list?
Can I create tables and without having it shown on the schema list?

Comment: Your question is bit confusing. If you are referring to the Database, try refreshing the database list once it is created. So that you will be able to see that.